# Running a data flow job with n2-standard-2 machine type , will the data flow job anytime run with only 2 vCPU's or it can auto scale to quota limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a question regarding data flow job for the machine type. I understand data flow uses default machine type as n1-standard-1 for batch processing and we have quota issues in asia-south1 for n1 machine type. We have been asked to use N2 machine type instead. So while creating the data flow template or while even running the data flow job from cloud shell, I am specifying the machine type as

```
python -m <Python script> \
--project <project> \
--region asia-south1 \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--staging_location <staging location> \
--temp_location <temp location> \
--subnetwork <sub network> \
--zone asia-south1-a \
--machine_type n2-standard-2 \
--save_main_session
```

My understanding is that machine type is what data flow uses when starting workers but in case of auto scaling and based on job, the numbers of vCPU's can be more based on project quota which is 32 CPU's now and data flow job will not limit it to just 2 vCPU's. In case my data flow job needs 4 vCPU's while running, it will get assigned irrespective of what I have mentioned while running or creating the data flow template as n2-standard-2.

Can some one please confirm my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [dataflow pipeline option](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options) you have 2 interesting parameters:

- `num_workers` which is the minimal number of worker that you want
- `max_num_workers` which is the max number of worker that you want

It your machine type is `n2-standard-2` and your n2 vCPU quotas is 32, you can't put more than 16 in the num_workers param (min or max). If you put 4 in the `max_num_workers` and even if your project quotas is 32 vCPU, the pipeline will be able to create only 4 n2-standard-2 VM, thus maximum 8 vCPU.

So, the project quota can limit you globally (for the Dataflow pipeline, and also others VM/GKE creation), and the `max_num_workers` limit only your current pipeline in number of workers (no direct relation with the number CPU, it depends on the machine type)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. I understand this now. Thanks much for your help as always. As we do not want to limit our pipelines now running with any specific number of workers and that it can scale up to the max number of workers based on the project quota(as we have auto scale on), I will just go with n2-standard-2 machine type without the max_num_workers parameter. So that the data flow job will start with 2 vCPU(one n2-standard-2)  and scale up to 32 vCPU's (16 n2-standard-2  VM). Kindly correct me if you think I still haven't got this right.

Comment: Yes you can. You should see errors in the logs (due to scaling out issue because of quota limit) but it won't break your pipeline.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere. Appreciate your help and time.